# Getting error: "Cannot use aggregate functions inside of aggregate functions". Need help in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table inside SQL Server called `tbl_contacts` which will look similar to this screenshot (*I have just highlighted few rows in yellow because those rows are going to get aggregated so that you can see difference between input and expected output*):

[image]

For my requirement, I created a view for all the data manipulations.
For an agent working in a team in a day, we wanted to find the avg talk time and max wait time.

I have written the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    Date, agentID, teamId,
    AVG([talk time]) AS avg_talk_time,
    MAX([wait time]) AS max_wait_time
FROM
    tbl_contacts
GROUP BY
    Date, agentID, teamId
```

Now, I have an additional requirement to add 2 columns,

1. The `CallStart` time whenever the wait time was maximum
2. The `CallEnd` time whenever the wait time was maximum.

Basically, whenever max wait time occurred in a day, we want to see when the call started and when the call ended.

I tried to extend my query like this:

```
SELECT
    Date, agentID, teamId,
    AVG([talk time]) AS avg_talk_time,
    MAX([wait time]) AS max_wait_time,
    MAX(CASE  
            WHEN [wait time] = MAX([wait time]) 
                THEN [Call Start] 
        END) AS [Wait Time Call Start],
    MAX(CASE 
            WHEN [wait time] = MAX([wait time]) 
                THEN [Call End] 
        END) AS [Wait Time Call End]
FROM
    tbl_contacts
GROUP BY 
    Date, agentID, teamId
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot use aggregate functions inside of aggregate functions.

I need your help with this SQL query.

I just need to return these 2 columns from my query.

I'm also attaching the screenshot of the expected output below so that it is clear:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The error, however, is telling you the problem. You probably want either a windowed aggregate or a CTE/derived table. Difficult to know without sample data and expected results (in a consumable format).

Comment: Sorry @ThomA. I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that using aggregate functions within aggregate functions is not permitted. One solution is to use your initial query as a subquery and join it to the table to obtain the related **call start** and **call end** values.

```
select s.*,
       [Call Start] as [Wait Time Call Start],
       [Call End] as [Wait Time Call End]
from tbl_contacts
inner join (
  Select Date, agentID, teamId, 
         AVG([talk time]) as avg_talk_time, 
         MAX([wait time]) as max_wait_time
  from tbl_contacts
  group by Date, AgentID, TeamID
) as s on s.Date = s.Date and s.agentID = t.agentID and s.teamId = t.teamId and s.max_wait_time = [wait time]
```

Comment: Hi @SelVazi. Even though this works. The main issue is when your tbl_contacts table has millions and millions of rows, then this query takes forever to run. I checked with few of my friends on whether there are any alternatives. Is there any other good way other than this which will help in running the query faster?

Comment: You need to add some indexes .. try this one : `CREATE INDEX idx_date_agent_team
    ON tbl_contacts(Date, agentID, teamId);`